# Adding edit button to each row of table to update database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've created a simple query of retrieving records from my database and passing it to a html. I want to add an edit/view button for each row so after some research, I ended up with this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM mytable") or die(mysqli_error($con));
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['pId']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['data1']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['data2']."</td>";
        echo "<td><form action='detailform.php' method='POST'><input type='hidden' name='tempId' value='".$row["pId"]."'/><input type='submit' name='submit-btn' value='View/Update Details' /><form></td>";
    }
}
```

This works fine for 1 record. But if I have 2 or more, the latest record is always retrieved regardless of which record you selected. For example, if you have 5 records and you select any record, the 5th record will always be selected so I am unable to update the previous records. Why is this is happening? Am I missing something?

Not sure if this helps my case but here's my the basic logic of my detailform.php:

```
if(isset($_POST["tempId"]){ 
     //pass data using post then update. Here's where I keep getting only the latest record regardless of selected record from previous page
} else { //add data }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close the form:

```
echo "<td><form action='detailform.php' method='POST'><input type='hidden' name='tempId' value='".$row["pId"]."'/><input type='submit' name='submit-btn' value='View/Update Details' /></form></td></tr>";
```

The first one is sent correctly because it is the closest to the submit button, the rest will be closer to the last submit button

Comment: Well doh *facepalms. I've been staring at code for 8 hours straight so I totally missed that one. Apparently, that's the only thing I'm missing. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['pId']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['data1']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['data2']."</td>";
        echo "<td><form action='detailform.php' method='POST'><input type='hidden' name='tempId' value='".$row["pId"]."'/><input type='submit' name='submit-btn' value='View/Update Details' /></form></td></tr>";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I did miss that </tr> at the end but it's still the same issue.

Comment: @@user1597438 ans has been updated... hope it ll solve your prob.. :)

Comment: Yep it does. I just missed the closing tag of form aside from the row. Thanks! :)